# SSL Network extender check point unable to have remote access intranet

Tags: remote-access

I'm trying to remotely connect to my desktop to have access to the private network of my company.

I have been able to run Java on Firefox. However, when it asks me to give access to execute Java and I accept it, the SSL Network extender (checkpoint) launches a terminal to install something. It asks me for my root password. As soon as I introduce the password the window closes throwing some error I am not able to capture.

I think the problem is that Ubuntu is not supported as a Linux OS for my company. What can I do? I really need to have remote access to the intranet.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have it solved. I am leaving here a small description of how I did it just in case someone else has the same problem.

1. Install Java in Ubuntu. You don't need the Oracle Version. You can download from Ubuntu Software Center
2. Enable Java in the browser.
3. Download the SSL Network extender from (link)

> The client software is only available for download from the firewall appliance itself. The VPN administrator must provide a URL (something like https://vpn.example.com/Login/Login) and credentials.
>
> There is a link to download the software. Click to save the file locally.

4. Unzip the file if it is a zip file
5. Execute the install_linux.sh (`sudo install_linux.sh` or `sudo snx_install.sh`)
6. Open the browser and enter in your remote access
7. Connect. If the snx launches the terminal but closes showing an error that you cannot read, it is probably a problem of dependences.

You may need to install the Vmware-view-client from the Ubuntu Software Center in this case. If you haven't enable the canonical software you will have to do it.

---

*Found details added to the answer*

> To access the VPN from a Linux host, a user logs into a web site using Firefox, then launches a Java applet, which runs a pre-installed local binary (snx) which initiates and configures the tunnel. The setup is elaborate and runs a setuid-root binary, so only attempt this if you trust the firewall server and its administrator, and if you are otherwise confident in the security of the Gentoo host.

<sup>source: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/SSL_Network_Extender#Download_the_client_install_script</sup>